# Parsing normal HTML string for tags IOS

Tags: html, iphone, parsing

Hi I am developing an iOS application in which I have a string containing some HTML tags. I want to parse the string and get the tags from it.

My string looks like this

`You can download the MyApp on the Google Play store:<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp' style='display:inline-block;padding:0px;margin-left:10px'>MyApp</a>",`

I just want to get tags like `href` tag value. How can I parse this thing. Moreover, I am not having any div and I just have a plain text. How to do this. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: can you use jquery to do this?

Comment: @EyalBarta I am using objective c native iPhone programming.

Comment: are you trying to parse an entire document, or just pull urls out of links?